# Usage of Negatives in Everyday Speach: Unnecessary or Incorrect

Tags: grammar, negation, speech

I frequently have this debate with my fiancée about whether it is as appropriate to use a negative in the following examples as it is to omit it.

I am frequently found making statements using the negative form seen below:

- *"I wonder if they **wouldn't** mind taking us with them this weekend."*

**vs**

- *"I wonder if they **would** mind taking us with them this weekend."*

**or**

- *"I wonder if it **wouldn't** be possible to substitute ham for turkey in my sandwich."*

**vs**

- *"I wonder if it **would** be possible to substitute ham for turkey in my sandwich."*

**Question**

1. Is it appropriate to use the negative form **"wouldn't"** in these sentences?

**Author's Viewpoint**

The way I see it, it is just as appropriate to wonder if something **was** possible is it would be to wonder if it **was not** possible. One may view this as inefficient speech but I don't believe it is incorrect; grammatically or otherwise.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give an explanation as to why this is correct or incorrect and the reasoning behind their position.

Comment: They are both correct. It's simply a matter of if you want to frame something in a positive or negative way.